# Change a timestamp to epoch use Bash get error like extra operand

Tags: bash, shell-script, date, timestamps

I define a variable in my Bash script like:

```
BIRTHDAY="1993-01-11 11:11 +08:00"
```

and convert it to epoches use `date` then `echo` with `echo $(date -d $BIRTHDAY +%s)`.

However, I get error: `date: extra operand ‘+08:00’`.

But, it works on a bash interactive shell:

```
➜  ~ BIRTHDAY="1993-01-11 11:11 +08:00"
➜  ~ date -d $BIRTHDAY +%s
726721860
➜  argos echo $(date -d $BIRTHDAY +%s)
726721860
```

I alse try to run `echo $(date -d \"$BIRTHDAY\" +%s)`, which not work too.

So, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 5):

You need to quote `"$BIRTHDAY"`, like this:

```
echo $(date -d "$BIRTHDAY" +%s)
```

It appears that you are actually using zsh as the interactive shell, as it is the only one in which this command will work correctly (with a default IFS value):

```
date -d $BIRTHDAY +%s
```

In any case, even in zsh, quoting the variable is helpful:

```
date -d "$BIRTHDAY" +%s
```